# Infowindow dialog balloon in my image

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I have a panel with pictures, like to do something similar infowindow the pin maker of googlemap, clicking on a umagem a balloon appears over the image with information.

[exemple](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/meBvOm)

```
<a id="infowindow"><img src='images/pic-01.jpg'></a>

<script>
    $("#infowindow").click(function(){
      alert("teste");
    });
</script>
```

Something like the orange balloon in the image below written "Rafael Meireles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the HTML to look something like this (note that `infowindow` is now a class):

```
<a class="infowindow">
    <img src='images/pic-01.jpg'>
</a>
<div class='infowindow-balloon'>Rafael Meireles</div>
```

The following jQuery will select the next element, which is the balloon, and toggle between showing and hiding it.

```
$(".infowindow").click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

This is the CSS to style the infowindow balloon:

```
.infowindow-balloon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: 60px;

  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f70;
  color: #fff;
}
```

This is the CSS to create the arrow on the left of the balloon:

```
.infowindow-balloon::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -20px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #f70;
}
```

This is the modified codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQdvdz

Comment: Sorry I'm new. How do I get it back to orignal state after the div lose focus?

Comment: The above code requires clicking the square picture icon to toggle between showing and hiding the balloon. If you want the balloon to show only when the cursor is hovering over the square picture icon, the jQuery snippet is not necessary and only CSS required is `.infowindow:hover + .infowindow-balloon { display: block; }`

Comment: If you want it to explicitly hide the balloon after the div loses focus, you can try ```$(".infowindow").on("blur", function(){
  $(this).next().hide();
});```